# How can I tell if an error occurred in a function call in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code structure:

```
callFunction()

if (there was an error in callFunction()){
    //Execute code
}
```

What can I put in place of 'there was an error in callFunction()' that will tell me an error was called in that function?  Is there line I should add to `callFunction` itself?

Comment: If "error" means "exception", see [`try..catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch). However, I generally consider exceptions *fatal* and encourage writing exception-free code in JavaScript - and returning "error / non-success indicators" as part of normal function return values. (Exceptions play a more accepted role in other languages.)

Comment: I was already implementing `try/catch` but I see how I can refactor my code to correctly use it here.  Thanks for prompting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try catch` is one way to do it. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

For example:

```
function myFunction() {

    try {
        //some code to execute
    }
    catch (e) {
        //throw an alert message if the try statement failed
        alert(e.toString());
    }
}
```